# wordpress jquery smooth scroll functionality

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scroll

I recently added this awesome plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-smooth-scroll/) to my website (http://chewonbamboo.com) to enable internal links to scroll nicely (i.e. http://chewonbamboo.com/brand-identity) but now the slider function on the homepage doesn't work when I click on the arrows. Is there a way to get these two features to play nicely with each other?

Comment: Have you checked the console for any JavaScript conflicts / errors?

Comment: @Ryan This came up on my brand-identity page, but I have no idea what this means :/ [link](http://chewonbamboo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Screen-Shot-2013-02-06-at-1.14.25-PM.png)